git merge conflict - common ancestor too old
We use Azure devops for development, there are 2 branches: stable and release.
When do development we create feature branch from release and create PR to merge it back to release (by default sqush commits is selected).
Then for every week's deployment we create PR to merge release to stable.
But today, Azure said there's conflict because some files are changed on both stable and release branch.
I checked out both branches and used git merge-base release stable and found the common base is the commit of tag 4.0.7. But stable is now at 4.0.9. Those files are changed between 4.0.7 and 4.0.9 so that's why we saw files are changed on both branches.
But the thing is, when you merge release to stable, isn't it that after the merge stable branch will be same as release, so when you merged release to stable, the new commit 4.0.9 becomes common base. I'm not sure why the common base is 4.0.7.
When creating PR from release to stable, there's no option for merge strategy because admin doesn't set it up I guess. Just want to see if anyone has similar experience and knows how to solve it. Thanks.

How do you "merge"? Do you use squash merges or regular merges (creating a new merge commit)?

on release branch I can see some merges have 1 commit so it's squshed, some merges have normal merge so each commit is copied to release. Release to stable seems to be always sqush commit

If you have squashed commits, you don't have a merge. Git does not and can not know what has been merged (because nothing was merged). That's your problem. Stop doing squashed commits and the merge base will be detected correctly.

you mean from release to stable?

I need to explain a bit. when feature->release, we can choose sqush or not, if yes there's 1 new commit in release branch, if not all commits are copied/reproduced on release branch. So I think relase branch is good enough.

@rhbc73 You need a basic understanding of what merge is and of what you're doing. I suggest you read my https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/. It covers everything you've described.

thanks Matt, my first merge was with IBM clearcase 19 years ago so I suppose I know merge very well, maybe it's no longer true. I'll have a read of the link tomorrow. But if I'm wrong, where is the problme, feature -> release or release -> stable?

The problem is squashing. Commits are not copied/reproduced when merging. Commits exist exactly once. When merging, a new commit is created, pointing to two or more parent commits. Squashing creates a new commit with a single parent, containing all changes again (so in a way, squash is what copies/reproduces the changes).

"so I suppose I know merge very well" This is Git, not IBM clearcase. I've read every word you've said here, and based on those words, I don't agree. My article covers what a Git merge is and what it is not; squashing is not a merge, and repeated squashing from one long-lived branch to another is a certain recipe for merge conflicts, and my article explains why. Moreover, these matters have already been dealt with at length here on SO.


when you merge release to stable, isn't it that after the merge stable branch will be same as release

It is not. When you merge release into stable, you're creating a new commit on stable's history. The head commit of release is still the same after the merge. The two branches do not point to the same commit.
Pre-merge
-- A -- B -- C    stable

-- J -- K -- L    release

Post-merge
-- A -- B -- C -- M   stable
                 /
                / 
-- J --- K --- L      release

If after a merge you wish for both branches to point to the same commit, you need to execute a second merge, which will be performed as a fast-forward, where the target branch and the other branch are swapped. In your case, it should have been as follows:
# making sure to be on stable
git checkout stable

# merging release into stable
git merge release

# making sure to be on release
git checkout release

# fast-forwarding release to stable's head commit
git merge stable

To change the merge base between release and stable, you could rebase on top of 4.0.9 the portion of commits that goes from 4.0.7 to release's tip. However, this requires warning every member of your team that is working on release or branched off release. Once all of their changes are integrated, you can proceed with the rebase.
git rebase --onto 4.0.9 4.0.7 release


Thanks dani-vta, but this doesn't explain why 4.0.7 is the common base,  4.0.7, 4.0.8 4.0.9 are on the generated commits on stable. In your example, it's M, and C has same content as M. In my case, both branches grew after M (4.0.7) was created.

@rhbc73 This is the issue. If you kept recording new commits on release without that second merge, both branches simply continued with their own history. It doesn't matter if their content is identical. Git only cares about commits. release probably continued on its own after the PR that created tag 4.0.7 on branch stable.

thanks dani-vta, but your first graph is wrong, I merge release to stable so M will be on stable. Could you update your graph and command so I can have a better understanding?

EDIT: release probably continued on its own, after the PR that created the merge commit with tag 4.0.7 on stable.

@rhbc73 updated the commit graph. Sorry, but I drew it while I was thinking about the second "swapped" merge. My bad.
